Is there any way to get the hash without sending the transaction
Is there any way to get the hash without sending the transaction.  I don't know what to do

The transaction hash is the first signature that signed the transaction. So if you sign a transaction, such as this (in Python)
sender_signature = keypair.sign_message(message.to_bytes_versioned(transaction_message))

The sender_signature would be the transaction hash for the transaction.

Transaction signatures mostly depend on the  Instructions, Fee Payer & Recent Blockhash, you can get the hash of the transaction as
let tx = new Transaction().add(ix);
tx.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
tx.sign(myKp);

// returns Uint8Array for signature 
console.log(tx.signature);

// also we can get it from signatures list as first signature is the hash
console.log(tx.signatures[0].signature);

// convert it to base58 encode (install bs58 library)
console.log(bs58.encode(tx.signature));

